# The Celebration

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, metapuzzles

Today is a very special day, a day for a party. It's time for a celebration, and you are invited. Here is my plan for our party today.

> First, we'll heat things up and have a shocking game of kickball.
>   Next, we'll listen to a gifted flutist beatbox some Imagine Dragons.
>   The third activity planned is a game of chess. Our opponent though, might scare you to death.
> After that, we'll play some Street Fighter. I'll play as Guile; his special move is my favorite.
>
> Our next activity, is a treasure hunt. We'll sing a whale song as we look for the prize.
> From there we'll play competitive rounds of twister. One on one games, where the loser is out.
> It's time to calm things down a bit with a card game with the king of hearts.
> It's time to eat, everyone give me your order. Only combos are allowed though, I have a coupon.
>
> We'll then play a game of Guess Who, where it's important to see and find out who you are.
> Will everyone be tired by then? I think so. Our next activity will be to perspire in a sauna.
> Afterwards it's time for a treat. Some ice cream sounds nice, don't you think?
> Is this too tiring? I hope not. We'll play a game of Two Truths and a Lie to shake things up.
>
> It's time to go classic, I'll get my SEGA. I think we'll play some Sonic Adventure.
> We'll wind things down now, with a story at the end. It's a great book, I just picked it up.

What am I celebrating?

Hint:

> It seems to me you're a bit confused. What could there be to possibly celebrate on a normal Thursday like this?
>  Well, I'll tell you this, **I** have a reason to celebrate.

Hint 2:

> It seems that our special [Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49913/guest) has seen a pattern in our activities planned for today. These activities do hold a special place in **my** heart.

Hint 3:

> In the past, every title to every puzzle I've used is a hint in some fashion. This puzzle is no different. The key is to find out what it means, it has something to do with SE.

Hint 4:

> What? Why yes, there are fourteen activities planned. It's not too much, is it?

Final Hint:

> What is the required amount of characters to submit a question, comment, or answer on Stack Exchange? If you follow that, and the activities I planned, you'll find the answer.

Comment: to be sure, for the second line, it's really a flutist, and not a cellist?

Comment: Yes, though I suppose more specifically, they're playing an instrument in the flute family.

Comment: It has something to do with 15, but what?

Comment: @Zani Xu hagfy had the right idea. You may want to look at his answer to come up with the correct one (as in, he mentions the right answer, but doesn't commit to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are you celebrating because you posted your 15th question on Thursday?

Based on Hagfy's answer,

> Every activity is based on one of your previous puzzles
>
>  Ball Lightning
>  Piccolo
>  Death
>  Sound Barrier / Sonic Boom
>
>  Narwhal
>  Knockout Tournament
>  Kingdom Hearts
>  French Fries
>
>  Reflection
>  Sweat
>  Blue Bell
>  Four Noble Truths
>
>  Dreams / Dreamcast
>  Library
>
> You have 14 activities, and this is your 15th. We also know of the number 15 because the final hint says that it has to do with the minimum number of characters, 15.

Comment: No, it's not. It's not an award that I'm celebrating, although you could say it's a an acheivement.

Comment: This probably is not even close, but are you turning 14?

Comment: Ha ha ha, no. I'm much older than that. The answer Im looking for is related to SE.

Comment: Ok, question: What does SE mean

Comment: Stack Exchange.

Comment: I changed it...

Comment: Hurray, you got it! I think something messed up in your latest edit though.

Comment: Me too... If you check the edit, can you find anything wrong? I'm new to this "spoilers" thing.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: BTW, The reason why I felt it would be worth celebrating was that it felt like I had past the minimum requirement to be a puzzler!

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Didn't hagfy mention this?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Yep definitely. I'm currently making a Puzzle around the Internet where it takes you to different sites. Is that allowed?

Comment: @ZaniXu Unfortunately not: puzzles on this site should be self-contained. EDIT: But thanks for asking first!

Comment: @noedne He did, but he mentioned it in passing. I told him in a comment that I'd accept his answer if he clarified a bit (since he listed three answers).

Comment: @noedne Aww fine then

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer**

Elaborating on @Guest's answer, and based on the hints:

> These are all based on the answers to your previous 14 puzzles
>
> Ball Lightning
> Piccolo
> Death (horseman)?  Not sure on this one, as 'death' is in the clue
> Sound Barrier / Sonic Boom
>
> Narwhal
> Knockout Tournament
> Kingdom Hearts
> French Fries
>
> Reflection
> Sweat
> Blue Bell
> Four Noble Truths
>
> Dreams / Dreamcast
> Library

Not sure where to take it from there.  Thoughts:

> The two answers I gave are similar to the answers for the 14 puzzles, but slightly different
>
> This is your 15th puzzle/question
>
> On Wednesday you hit 1000 rep, becoming an Established User who can create gallery chat rooms.  You also earned Custodian and Mortarboard on Tuesday.  Not sure these are relevant as you're specifying 'Thursday' as important.

---

**CORRECT**

After that, we'll play some Street Fighter. I'll play as Guile; his special move is my favorite.

> **SONIC BOOM**
> Guile's signature move

It's time to go classic, I'll get my SEGA. I think we'll play some Sonic Adventure.

> **DREAMCAST**
> It's the SEGA console that Sonic Adventure came out on

Comment: The Street Fighter clue and the SEGA clue are correct. The others are wrong. All these clues will lead you to something so you can find out what I'm celebrating.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Thanks for the response.  Added a second guess for the second clue, similar to the first guess.

Comment: I added the lateral thinking tag to this puzzle as well. Some clues aren't very direct to their approach. The second clue is wrong again. If this is getting too difficult, I'll add a hint in a couple hours.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Ah, I see.  It's only been a couple hours, so I wouldn't worry about hints just yet.  It's likely only too difficult **for me**.  =)

Comment: One of your final answers is correct. All the clues are right too. look at the final hint and tell me the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> YOU have been Awarded the badge Mortarboard

because

> your clues reference your other questions and riddles

Comment: This is actually not the answer I'm looking for. But you're on the right track by searching like that.

Comment: You may also want to check out the new hint I added, because you were so close already.